# T-SQL Pivot Row to Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I am using SQL Server 2012 and have a table that has the following columns:

ID, Date, CustomFieldName, CustomFieldValue

The CustomFieldName column has 100 values (I know how stupid this sounds) but for the sake of simplicity lets say they are CustomField1, CustomField2, CustomField3

I would like to create a pivot where the out put looks like

ID, Date, CustomField1, CustomField2, CustomField3 where the Max date of CustomFieldVaue's is aggregated.

I have failed horribly in this, but have some progress (though my max isnt right and getting a lot of wrong data)

Any help would be appreciated!

```
SELECT [date],[id], [CustomField1], [CustomField2], [CustomField3]
from
(
  SELECT [date], [id], [CustomFieldValue], [CustomFieldName], 
    row_number() over(partition by [CustomFieldName] order by [CustomFieldValue]) rn
  from CustomTable
) as st
pivot
(
  max([CustomFieldValue])
  FOR [CustomFieldName] in ([CustomField1], CustomField2, [CustomField3])
) as pivottable
order by [id]
```

Comment: omit the `id` and it will work the way you want it to.

Answer (score 1):

Hope I got it right, you want to pivot the rows (COlumnName1,2,...etc) as columns, so I've made a little script that's ready to run.

I recommend CTE's when it comes to pivoting, makes it easier, if you want to see the whole structure of the query just do  a `select @xSqlString`

```
set nocount on;

create table 
    #testTable 
        (
            ID                  int identity(1,1),
            [Date]              datetime default getdate(),
            CustomFieldName     nvarchar(50),
            CustomFieldValue    date
        );

declare
    @i int = 0,
    @xSqlStringPivot  nvarchar(max) = '',
    @xSqlString       nvarchar(max) = '';

while(@i<=100)
begin

set
    @xSqlStringPivot += concat('CustomFieldName',cast(@i as nvarchar(50)),char(13), case when @i<100 then ', ' else '' end);

insert into #testTable
    (
        CustomFieldName,
        CustomFieldValue
    )
values
    (
        concat('CustomFieldName', cast(@i as nvarchar(50))),
        dateAdd(day,-@i,getdate())
    );

set
    @i += 1;

end;


select * from
    #testTable


set
    @xSqlString = 
        (
            'with ctePiv as
            (
            select
                t.CustomFieldName,
                t.CustomFieldValue
            from
                #testTable t
            )
            select
                *
            from
                ctePiv
            pivot
            (
                max(customFieldValue) for customFieldName in
                    (
                    '+ @xSqlStringPivot +'          
                    )
            )p'
        );

exec sp_executeSQL @xSqlString


drop table #testTable;
```

**Edit 1**

1. I am referencing the custom table on the while block, basically I'm iterating 100 times to populate the table with 100 rows. This is just to simulate your case.

   while(@i<=100)
   begin

   set
       @xSqlStringPivot += concat('CustomFieldName',cast(@i as nvarchar(50)),char(13), case when @i<100 then ', ' else '' end);

   insert into #testTable
       (
           CustomFieldName,
           CustomFieldValue
       )
   values
       (
           concat('CustomFieldName', cast(@i as nvarchar(50))),
           dateAdd(day,-@i,getdate())
       );

   set
       @i += 1;

   end;
2. @xSqlStringPivot is just a small trick to make a list of elements (CustomFieldName0, CustomFieldName1, etc) and to concatenate it to a dynamic SQL string, notice that I'm doing this in the while block, I just concatenate 'CustomField' with the current iteration number and with a carry feed (space).

Comment: Couple questions on this script and I apologize ahead for my ignorance!  1.  I see you are using a temp table but where are you referencing the CustomTable to load the initial data?  2.  CustomFieldValue can be anything  (strings, dates, ints, etc.) my goal would be to refer to these as strings as it will be just used to review the data.  3. For each ID, I need to get the Max Request_date

Comment: Sure, ask away, I also apologize for not explaining the whole script, I will re-write my answer accordingly

Comment: Please check the main thread, I've done a small edit related to your 1'st question. What do you mean 'to review the data' ? By max request date you mean that you can have multiple rows with the same CustomValueName  but with different values ?